# What are Alpha only icons?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-notifications, alpha

As per Android L developers guide [here](https://developer.android.com/preview/api-overview.html),

> The system ignores all non-alpha channels in action icons and the main
> notification icon. You should assume that these icons are alpha-only.

So my question is very simple: what are alpha-only icons? and how does it affect the UI? What are the things that I have to update in my project which was targeted previously for jelly bean?

I searched on google but couldn't find any answer for this.

Answer (score 2):

Alpha is from a graphical background,
and in Google docs it refers to Icons with transparent Background

Graphical definition

> Alpha channels are masks through which you can display images. The
>   alpha channel is an 8-bit channel, which means it has 256 levels of
>   gray from 0 (black) to 255 (white). White acts as the visible area;
>   black acts as the transparent area

Comment: can you answer second? - What are the things that I have to update in my project which was targeted previously for jelly bean?

Comment: which means they are saying that icons in notifications must be with transparent background? right?

Comment: only background need to be transparent?