# Toolbar icon tinting on Android

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-toolbar, android-icons

I've noticed that using AppCompat themes, default toolbar icons get tinted by the attribute `colorControlNormal` in my style.

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/yellow</item>
</style>
```

[image]

As you can see above, however, it does not happen with all icons. I provided the "plus" sign, which I got from the official icons, and it does not get tinted (I used the "white" version of the png). From what I have understood from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25889242/what-are-alpha-only-icons), system tints only icons with just an alpha channel. Is this true?

**If so**: Is there a place where I can find alpha-defined, official material icons? If not - and if Toolbar icons need to be alpha-only to be tinted - how is Google expecting us to use provided icons in a Toolbar?

Somewhere in the SDK I found some icons ending in `_alpha.png`, and they actually get tinted well. However I need the full set of material icons, and from the official sources I could only find `white`, `grey600` and `black` ones.

Applying a `ColorFilter` at runtime would be slightly painful, and my actual Toolbar - with some icons tinted, some others not - looks quite bad.

Comment: AppCompat only tints its own icons. For now, you will need to manually tint any icons that you're providing separately from AppCompat.

Comment: Also, the linked question only applies to notifications, not general tinting.

Comment: See also [this StackO-Post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26780046/menuitem-tinting-on-appcompat-toolbar) for a thorough explanation.

Comment: Looks like I should have searched a bit longer. I will gladly accept your answer @alanv , or let's flag this as a duplicate. Out of curiosity, you do say "for now" because you know about a fix coming, or you just imagine so?

Comment: It's something that we'd like to do, but I can't make any promises.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I see this question is getting some views so I'm going to post an answer for those who don't read the comments.

My conjectures in the question were all wrong and it is not a matter of alpha channels, at least not externally. The fact is simply that, quoting @alanv ,

> AppCompat only tints its own icons. For now, you will need to manually
>   tint any icons that you're providing separately from AppCompat.

This might change in the future but also might not. From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26817918/4288782) you can also see the list of icons (they all belong to the internal resource folder of appcompat, so you can't change them) that are automatically tinted and with which color.

Personally I use a `colorControlNormal` which is black or white (or similar shades), and import the icons with that particular color. Colored icons on a colored background look a little bad. However, another solution I found pleasant is [this class](https://gist.github.com/jaredrummler/ec7dfb73f3235ad8e951) on github. You just call `MenuColorizer.colorMenu()` when you create the menu.

Comment: It's seems like the java class have been changed

Answer (score 40):

Another option is to use the new support for vector drawables in the support library.

See `res/xml/ic_search.xml` in blog post [AppCompat — Age of the vectors](https://medium.com/@chrisbanes/appcompat-v23-2-age-of-the-vectors-91cbafa87c88)

Notice the reference to `?attr/colorControlNormal`

```
<vector xmlns:android="..."
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportWidth="24.0"
    android:viewportHeight="24.0"
    android:tint="?attr/colorControlNormal">
    <path
        android:pathData="..."
        android:fillColor="@android:color/white"/>
</vector>
```

Comment: What's the difference between using `?attr/colorControlNormal` at `android:tint` vs `android:fillColor` attributes? Thanks!

Comment: @SuperThomasLab The example is from Chris Banes's blog where it illustrates replacing a tinted image with a tinted vector. Note that the fillColor was effectively hard-coded in the source image. I do not know if other color representations are now supported in AppCompat.

Comment: I was looking a long time for this answer. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 23):

Here is the solution that I use. Call tintAllIcons after onPrepareOptionsMenu or the equivalent location. The reason for mutate() is if you happen to use the icons in more than one location; without the mutate, they will all take on the same tint.

```
public class MenuTintUtils {
    public static void tintAllIcons(Menu menu, final int color) {
        for (int i = 0; i < menu.size(); ++i) {
            final MenuItem item = menu.getItem(i);
            tintMenuItemIcon(color, item);
            tintShareIconIfPresent(color, item);
        }
    }

    private static void tintMenuItemIcon(int color, MenuItem item) {
        final Drawable drawable = item.getIcon();
        if (drawable != null) {
            final Drawable wrapped = DrawableCompat.wrap(drawable);
            drawable.mutate();
            DrawableCompat.setTint(wrapped, color);
            item.setIcon(drawable);
        }
    }

    private static void tintShareIconIfPresent(int color, MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getActionView() != null) {
            final View actionView = item.getActionView();
            final View expandActivitiesButton = actionView.findViewById(R.id.expand_activities_button);
            if (expandActivitiesButton != null) {
                final ImageView image = (ImageView) expandActivitiesButton.findViewById(R.id.image);
                if (image != null) {
                    final Drawable drawable = image.getDrawable();
                    final Drawable wrapped = DrawableCompat.wrap(drawable);
                    drawable.mutate();
                    DrawableCompat.setTint(wrapped, color);
                    image.setImageDrawable(drawable);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This won't take care of the overflow, but for that, you can do this:

Layout:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    ...
    android:theme="@style/myToolbarTheme" />
```

Styles:

```
<style name="myToolbarTheme">
        <item name="colorControlNormal">#FF0000</item>
</style>
```

This works as of appcompat v23.1.0.

Answer (score 17):

I actually was able to do this on API 10 (Gingerbread) and it worked very well.

**Edit**: It worked on API 22 also...

Here's the final result.

[image]

Note: The icon is a drawable resource in the drawable folder(s).

Now here's how its done:

```
@Override
public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);

    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_refresh);
    Drawable icon = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_refresh_white_24dp);
    icon.setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);

    item.setIcon(icon);
}
```

At this point you can change it to any color you want!

Answer (score 16):

That's the final and true answer
First create style for toolbar like this:

```
  <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" >
     <item name="iconTint">@color/primaryTextColor</item>
    <!--choice your favorite color-->
  </style>
```

Then in your main app or activity theme add this line

```
  <item name="actionBarPopupTheme">@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay</item>
```

And finally in you'r layout file add this line to toolbar

```
 android:theme="?attr/actionBarPopupTheme"
```

And Then you will see your toolbar icons colored in your favorite color

Answer (score 6):

For sdk 23 or higher:

```java
<style name="AppThemeToolbar" parent="MyAppTheme">
        ....
        <item name="android:drawableTint">@color/secondaryLightColor</item>
    </style>
```

My toolbar

```java
    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content">
      <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
          android:theme="@style/AppThemeToolbar"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="attr/actionBarSize">
      </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

Answer (score 5):

You could just create a custom Toolbar that uses your tint color when inflating the menu.

```
public class MyToolbar extends Toolbar {
    ... some constructors, extracting mAccentColor from AttrSet, etc

    @Override
    public void inflateMenu(@MenuRes int resId) {
        super.inflateMenu(resId);
        Menu menu = getMenu();
        for (int i = 0; i < menu.size(); i++) {
            MenuItem item = menu.getItem(i);
            Drawable icon = item.getIcon();
            if (icon != null) {
                item.setIcon(applyTint(icon));
            }
        }
    }
    void applyTint(Drawable icon){
        icon.setColorFilter(
           new PorterDuffColorFilter(mAccentColor, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN)
        );
    }

}
```

Just make sure you call in your Activity/Fragment code:

```
toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.some_menu);
toolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener(someListener);
```

No reflection, no view lookup, and not so much code, huh?

And don't use `onCreateOptionsMenu/onOptionsItemSelected`, if you use this approach

Answer (score 1):

With androidX you can define your Toolbar like this

```xml
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:theme="@style/Toolbar" />
```

Then, extend an AppCompat theme and set colorControlNormal property as you like:

```xml
<style name="Toolbar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/colorBaseWhite</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/colorPrimary</item>
</style>
```

Comment: The key here is that specifying a theme for the Toolbar allows you to use `?attr/` references for your colors.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in Kotlin with:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    menu.getItem(0)?.icon?.setTint(Color.WHITE)
}
else {
    @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
    menu.getItem(0)?.icon?.setColorFilter(Color.WHITE, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN)
}
```

It should work on all modern versions of Android, and will fail without a crash if `getItem` or `icon` returns null.

Answer (score 1):

try this ...

```
  menu.getItem(0).getIcon().setTint(Color.parseColor("#22CC34"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@NonNull
public static Drawable setTintDrawable(@NonNull Drawable drawable, @ColorInt int color) {
   drawable.clearColorFilter();
   drawable.setColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
   drawable.invalidateSelf();
   Drawable wrapDrawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(drawable).mutate();
   DrawableCompat.setTint(wrapDrawable, color);
   return wrapDrawable;
 }
```

> and call in this manner:

```
MenuItem location = menu.findItem(R.id.action_location);
DrawableUtils.setTintDrawable(location.getIcon(), Color.WHITE);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Basically, when you set menu, the three-dot icon takes up the color of **android:textColorSecondary** from the AppTheme, which in default is set to Black.

So if you are not using, textColorSecondary anywhere in your project, then you can simply add the following line

```
<item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/White</item>
```

After adding it may look like this.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customise your theme here. -->

    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/White</item>
</style>
```