# Toolbar customization

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-toolbar, android-support-design

I'm using `25.3.1` support library. I have `Fragment` in my app with `setHasOptionsMenu(true)`. After menu has been inflated, menu icons does not accept color from styles, they stay black (as original vector resource) instead of my text color as I wrote in styles. What am I doing wrong?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    >

  <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
      android:id="@+id/toolbar"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
      android:background="@color/toolbarBackgroundColor"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Toolbar"
      app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
      />
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Here is toolbar style:

```
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
  ...
  </style>

  <style name="AppTheme.Toolbar" parent="Base.ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@color/textColor</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/textColor</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/textColor</item>
  </style>
```

And here is my code from `Fragment`

```
  @Override
  public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    mTopLevelModeEnabled = true;
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.order_menu, menu);
  }
```

Comment: Can you post a screenshot with actual and desired behavior?

Comment: @azizbekian, unfortunately, no. But I can explain. I have black icons in my drawables  folder. My textColor is light gray. Toolbar title, home icon and menu items without icon (just text) is light gray except menu items with icon attribute, they are black

Comment: This may be relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28219178/toolbar-icon-tinting-on-android