# Tint Navigation Icon in Toolbar

Tags: android, icons, android-toolbar, tint

How to tint menu icons is already covered a few times, like here:
[Toolbar icon tinting on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28219178/toolbar-icon-tinting-on-android)

Additionally to this solution there is still the problem of the navigation icon. 
Applying a Theme(Overlay) to your Toolbar just tints the text and the whitelisted icons (see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26817918/2417724)

If you set a custom icon (which happens to be quite easy the case, as you need to change it if you don't want to display the default back arrow) then this custom icon does not get tinted.

How do you handle your Icons then?
All my icons are per default black and I don't want to have special white versions just to use them in the Toolbar then.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The appcompat navigation button - which is simply an `AppCompatImageButton` - can be styled through the `toolbarNavigationButtonStyle` attribute. The default style for that in the `AppCompat` themes is `Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar.Button.Navigation`, and we can extend that style to add a `tint` attribute value. For example:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    ...

    <item name="toolbarNavigationButtonStyle">@style/Toolbar.Button.Navigation.Tinted</item>

</style>

<style name="Toolbar.Button.Navigation.Tinted" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar.Button.Navigation">
    <item name="tint">@color/nav_button_tint</item>
</style>
```

---

There are a couple of caveats to be aware of when using this method.

Prior to support library version 25.4.0, `AppCompatImageButton` did not offer its own `tint` attribute, and therefore a `tint` attribute in the app's namespace will not apply (and just won't exist, unless defined elsewhere). It is necessary to use the platform `android:tint` attribute if using support library version 25.3.0 or earlier.

Unfortunately, this leads to another catch, in that the platform tint prior to Lollipop (API level 21) can handle only simple, single color values, and using a `ColorStateList` (`<selector>`) resource value will cause an `Exception` to be thrown. This poses no problems if the `android:tint` value is a simple color, but it is often desired to tint the navigation icon to match another theme color attribute, which may very well be a `ColorStateList`. In this case, it would be necessary to create separate styles in `res/values/` and `res/values-21/`, specifying a simple color value for `android:tint` in `res/values/`.

For example, if tinting to match the theme's primary text color:

`res/values/styles.xml`

```
<item name="android:tint">@color/normal_text_color</item>
```

`res/values-v21/styles.xml`

```
<item name="android:tint">?android:textColorPrimary</item>
```

You need only concern yourself with the notes above if you're stuck using a support library version less than 25.4.0.

Comment: Worked! Note that it's slightly confusing since the answer gives examples with both `<item name="tint">` and `<item name="android:tint">`, but simply `<item name="tint">` as seen in the first example works correctly! Thank you Mike!

Comment: The snippets in the second part apply only to support library versions less than 25.4.0. It's highly unlikely that you're using a version that old, at this time. If one were to be stuck with such a legacy version, you'd have to use the platform `tint` attribute, which is in the platform namespace, thus the `android` prefix – `android:tint`. For newer versions, including androidx, you use the library's `tint` attribute, which is in your app's namespace, so no prefix – just `tint`. I tried to clearly delineate those separate solutions with the horizontal rule. Sorry if it wasn't clear.

Comment: YOU ARE THE BEST @MikeM.

Answer (score 0):

To effectively set the tint color of the navigation icon programmatically you need to set the drawable first and apply the tint afterwards.

```
toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_back)
toolbar.children.forEach {
    (it as? AppCompatImageButton)?.imageTintList =
            ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.GREEN)
    it.refreshDrawableState()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to tint the icon

```java
   toolbar.getNavigationIcon().setTint(getColor(R.color.white));
```